Connecting PIR Motion Detector with RF Transmitter
I'm working on a project to create a wireless motion detector using a PIR sensor and an RF transmitter. Both circuits function well independently, but when I connect them, I encounter issues. Specifically, the output from the BISS0001 PIR IC remains high or occasionally blinks when the circuits are connected.
To clarify:
The PIR sensor outputs a high signal when motion is detected.
The RF transmitter is activated to send a signal when its input is triggered.
I designed the PIR circuit based on the BISS0001 datasheet. For the RF transmitter, I used a remote control board as a reference. After identifying the connections with a multimeter, I replicated the circuit on my board, replacing the push button with a transistor (Q4 in the schematic).
First picture is the transmitter and the second one is the motion detector.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly connect these two circuits without interference.
Thank you in advance for your help!



The input connection to your RF-Transmitter is a mess and probably the reason to your issues. What do you want to do there? I guess you want to enable Vcc and pull the input K0 high at the same time. But you're putting the LED D1 in series with Vcc? Also, what is that Connection between the Base of Q3 and the collector of Q4 for?

@kruemi I want in the case of motion detection, RF send a signal. I thought if connect the BISS output to the base of transistor to drive the 5V to the transmitter it could work.

do you know how bipolar Transistors work? Q3 can't start to conduct because a current would have to flow trom collector to base which can't happen because the only path for current would be trough Q4 in K0 of J1 but K0 is high impedance.

@kruemi I know I have made a mistake in the vout of BISS0001. But I do not how I should connect its output to the transmitter to transmit signal. when PIR detects a motion there is a 5v signal in the out put of BISS0001. I supposed, if I connect this 5v to the base of an NPN transistor (Q4) it must work. In addition, I used another NPN (Q5) to boost 5v signal and also for seeing detection I used Q6 and D2. Which seems I was totally wrong.
Probably I should remove Q2, Q4, Q5 and Q6, but I do not know what circuitry is correct to turn on the transmitter by the Vout of BISS0001.
